# Collapse selected code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

I Want to collapse code like a function or a class using eclipse. Is there any package that can help me do that? It would be good if I could collapse the selected code and expand when needed.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the Java editor, you should see a little dash in a bubble next to the line number at the start of each function.  Clicking that will hide the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke HideShow mode with M-x hs-minor-mode.

then use :
C-c @ C-s to show block and 
C-c @ C-h hide block